# OpenGL ES 2- Android fatal signal 11 SIGSEGV

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I created a 3D rotating cube with diffuse lighting on OpenGL ES 2. Then i tried adding a 3D model in place of the cube. After a lot of searching, i somehow managed to extract the vertices from .obj file but when i put them in my code, i get the following error:

**Java - Android fatal signal 11 SIGSEGV**

There are others who had similar problem and asked the same question. Many people say that the buffer wasn't big enough. The following is my code when i initialize the vertex buffer. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    mCubePositions = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cubePositionData.length * mBytesPerFloat)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mCubePositions.put(cubePositionData).position(0);
```

Comment: Nthng is wrng with these lines. Once checkout wer it is getting by printing some logCat at each line.

Comment: Thanks. But i solved the error. It was because i was using GlDrawArrays(... ,..., number of vertices *3). All i had to do was just pass in the number of vertices and not the total elements in my position array...